# Marginal pdf does not exist?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose 2 random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the following joint probability density function:

$\qquad f_{X,Y}(x,y) = c/y$ for $0<x<y<1$; $0$ otherwise

Find the marginal probability of $X$ and $Y$

I found the $c$ to be $1$,

and
$f_{X}(x)$ should be $\int_{x}^{1} \frac 1y \,dy $ , right?

in that case, $f_{X}(x)$ would be $-\ln x$

Which doesn't really make sense

I wonder what went wrong in my thought process

Thank you!!!

Comment: $-\ln x, 0<x<1 $ is a  pdf. Why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: Actually $X=UY$ where $Y$ and $U$ are uniform on $(0,1)$ and independent. Your proof for the density ox $X$ is quite correct.

Comment: I would have thought this might be called a *logarithmic distribution*, but apparently that is [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_distribution).

Comment: The pdf can diverge at some points. The key feature: it remains integrable to $1$, which you can easily check.

Comment: Ahhhh thank you guys, I was not paying enough attention to the domain, after i got -lnx I tried to see if it makes sense by putting in values because I have seen that pdf before, and since I plugged in values greater than 1 I got negative probabilities!